# What is the actual range of a MySQL INT column in this situation?

Tags: mysql

Ok, so I know that the INT type in MySQL has a range of either 0 to 4,294,967,295 or of -2,147,483,648 to 2,147,483,647
[MySQL reference](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/integer-types.html)

My question is if I have a single row in an INT column with a value of -1 and all other rows are positive numbers, what is the actual range of that column?  Because it has a single negative number, does the column automatically have a range of -2,147,483,648 to 2,147,483,647, or is the range more dynamic and instead is -1 to 4,294,967,294?

Comment: easy to test insert first  4,294,967,294, then update same cell value with -2,147,483,648. Then alter your column as 'INT UNSIGNED DEFAULT 1' so try again. Then you will see if its dynamic unless you specified.

Comment: Also dont worry for downvote wondering is always good

Comment: Thanks!  I was a little annoyed at that initial downvote as I put a lot of effort into following the posting rules. But I guess that's just what happens sometimes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The ranges you are seeing in the MySQL reference are describing whether or not you add in `SIGNED` (the default if left blank) or `UNSIGNED` as an attribute in your column definition. E.g., `CREATE TABLE my_table(column_1 INT UNSIGNED...)`.

If you specify `UNSIGNED` you extend the upper bound of the data type (assuming the data type in question has a `SIGNED`/`UNSIGNED` option), but you also lose the lower end of the range. If you specify `SIGNED` or don't specify anything at all (then the default `SIGNED` will apply) then your upper bound is the upper bound of the `SIGNED` range.

So, for a `SIGNED` column of type `INT` (or if no attribute is specified), your range is -2,147,483,648 to 2,147,483,647. If you specify `UNSIGNED` your range is 0 to 4,294,967,295, and you would not actually be able to put -1 in that column and have it be properly stored as -1. Per http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/out-of-range-and-overflow.html, MySQL "stores the value representing the corresponding endpoint of that range" for integers. So inserting -1 into an `UNSIGNED` integer column will store 0 instead. If you need to store negative integer values, you need to use `SIGNED`. If you need an extended upper range and don't need to store negative numbers, you would want to use the `UNSIGNED` attribute.

Answer (score 2):

So to be more specific about the `INT` datatype; you can have either `INT UNSIGNED` or `INT SIGNED`. This is set when the column is created. I believe it defaults to `SIGNED` if you don't specify. So any `INT` column is either `SIGNED` or `UNSIGNED` and this is NOT dynamic.

`INT UNSIGNED` has the range `0 to 4,294,967,295`

`INT SIGNED` has the range `-2,147,483,648 to 2,147,483,647`

So if even one row has a negative value, you have to use `INT SIGNED`. Giving the column the range `-2,147,483,648 to 2,147,483,647`.

Answer (score 0):

The range of 0 to 4,294,967,295 is for `UNSIGNED`. As an example:

```
...
`type` int(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL DEFAULT '0'
...
```

You have to specifically set the unsigned state for the column otherwise it is considered signed which will have the range of -2,147,483,648 to 2,147,483,647

Answer (score 0):

No, the ranges are not dynamically adjusted to the filled data. `SIGNED` and `UNSIGNED` ranges are raw ranges, regardless what the table already contains.

```
CREATE TABLE `testing` (
    `x` INT(11) NULL DEFAULT NULL
)
ENGINE=InnoDB
;

INSERT INTO testing VALUES (-1);
SELECT * FROM testing;
INSERT INTO testing VALUES (4000000000);
SELECT * FROM testing;
```

Returns "Out of range error", and data will be "-1 ; 2147483647" (greatest `SIGNED INT` 32 bits)